# how to plot labels in group boxplot

Tags: r, label, boxplot

I have a boxplot separated by categories, I need to plot the values ​​of the first quartile, median, third quartile in all boxplot, but I can not. I have the following code:

```
  a <- runif(10,1,100)
  b <-c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
  t <- cbind(a,b)     

  bp<- boxplot(a~b)
```

I can get the values ​​through the bp$stats command, but I can not plot in each boxplot (three factors/three boxplots), can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you would like to plot the values on the boxplots. This can be achieved using the function `text`:

```
bp <- boxplot(a~b)   
text(x = 1, y = bp$stats[,1] + 2, labels = round(bp$stats[,1], 2))
text(x = 2, y = bp$stats[,2] + 2, labels = round(bp$stats[,2], 2))
```

[image]

using the `bp$stats` values as coordinates and nudging them to the top by adding 2 so the do not overlap with the graphic. The same values should be used as labels.

You mention three boxplots in the question, is it a mistake or I did not understand?